# Want to show a string and a variable in 2nd argument of a messagebox

Tags: c++, winapi, messagebox

I have been creating a registration window in an app, I want to display "You are registered with username - " in an MessageBoxA.
I have stored the value in char User[25]; and char Pass[25];

```
char *u = &User[0];
char *p = &Pass[0];
int gwtu = GetWindowText(tFieldU,u,25);
int gwtp = GetWindowText(tFieldP,p,25);
MessageBoxA(wh,"What should be here?","Registration Compelete!",MB_OK);
```

I want to keep it simple and short. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the strings together, and then pass the result to `MessageBoxA`. There are a myriad of methods to do this, inside and outside the standard library. One simple way is `strcat` (from header `<cstring>`). Make sure the destination array is big enough to hold both strings, as well as the null terminator.

```
char message[200] = "You are registered with username - ";
std::strcat(message, User);

MessageBoxA(wh, message, "Registration Compelete!", MB_OK);
```

Another option is to use `ostringstream` (from `<sstream>`) to build a string, and then call `c_str()` on that string which you can then pass to `MessageBoxA`.

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "You are registered with username - " << User;
std::string message = oss.str();
MessageBoxA(wh, message.c_str(), "Registration Compelete!", MB_OK);
```